# How to add a child to the last node in an XML file using PHP5?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

here's what i'm trying to do

i currently have:

```
<sessions>
  <session>
    <event>milk</event>
  </session>
  <session>
    <event>graze</event>
  </session>
</sessions>
```

i want to go to the very last "session" node and add a new event

```
<event>health treatment</event>
```

so it'd look like:

```
<sessions>
  <session>
    <event>milk</event>
  </session>
  <session>
    <event>graze</event>
    <event>health treatment</event>
  </session>
</sessions>
```

i tried simpleXML's xpath and registering the pathname,  i found some examples on this site but no success
i'd prefer to use simpleXML but if dom's the only solution then i'll use it, i did not manage to do this in dom either

here's my script (i commented some bits out for when i was experimenting):

```
<?php
$session = $_POST['session'];
$event = $_POST['event'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file("sessions.xml"); 
//$xml->registerXPathNamespace('o', 'http://obix.org/ns/schema/1.0');

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());

if(isset($session)){
$item = $sxe->addChild("session");
}else{
list($item) = $xml->xpath('/sessions/session[last()]');
$item->name = 'Jane Smith';
//$item = $sxe->children('session[last()]');
//$xpath = '/o:sessions/o:session[last()]';
//$item = $xml->xpath($xpath);
}
$item->addChild("event", $event);
$sxe->asXML("sessions.xml"); 
?>
```

or if you know a better way to do this then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily jump to the last child of an element using [SimpleXMLElement::count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php)

For example

```
$lastSession = $xml->session[$xml->session->count() - 1];
$lastSession->addChild('event', $event)
```